# My simple login system using SQLite3 doesn't seem to get the matching ID/Password from the database

Tags: python, database, forms, sqlite, authentication

This is my first post ever on Stackoverflow.

I wrote a simple code for a login system using SQLite3 and when I type the right ID and password in the login form made with Tkinter, it doesn't let me through and I just do not know why. I tried everything that ChatGPT told me to do but it still doesn't work.

Can everyone help me pinpoint what's the issue?

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

#------------------------------DB------------------------------------
#connect to the DB
con = sqlite3.connect('SeaSideDB.db')
#execute SQL statements and fetch results from SQL queries (the object 'con' represents the connection to the on-disk DB)
cur = con.cursor()
#create a table 
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(ID,PASSWORD)")
#verifying that the new table's been created by querying the table
res = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master")
#add rows of data supplied as SQL literals by exercuting an INSERT statement
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO login VALUES 
        ('Juke',1234)
""")
#call this to commit the transaction 
con.commit() 
res = cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM login")
res.fetchall()
#---------------------------END OF DB------------------------------------


#--------------------------LOGIN GUI--------------------------------------
root = Tk(className = 'Seaside Loyalty Login') 
root.geometry("500x150")
#ID input
L = Label(root, text = "ID")
T = Text(root, height = 1, width = 25)
L.config(font =("Courier",13))
L.pack()
T.pack()

#password input 
L1 = Label(root, text = "Password")
T1 = Text(root, height = 1, width = 25)
L1.config(font =("Courier",13))
L1.pack()
T1.pack()
#----------------------------END OF LOGIN GUI-----------------------------------

#function that checks to see if the ID and PASSWORD match 
def login(ID, PASSWORD):
    cur = con.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE ID = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (ID, PASSWORD))
    result = cur.fetchone() 
    if result: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False

#button function for credentials and it checks to see if the ID and PASSWORD entered by the user match the ones stored in DB. 
def check_credentials():
    ID = T.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    PASSWORD = T1.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip() 
    if login(ID, PASSWORD):
        messagebox.showinfo("Login","Successful")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login", "Invalid ID or Password")

#button input 
B = Button(root, text = "Login", command = check_credentials)
B.place_configure(rely = 0.1)
B.pack() 


root.mainloop()
#close DB after program exits 
con.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

It seems like the DB was set up right but I think the problem comes from getting the table from the DB and matching it to the input on the login form.

Comment: Why are you using `Text` instead of `Entry` for the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

`T1.get()` returns a string, but you stored an integer in the `PASSWORD` column of the table. Change this column to a string:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO login VALUES 
        ('Juke','1234')
""")
```

You could also specify the datatypes of the columns in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!
I want the password to be a mix of letters/numbers/symbols so I would use Entry instead of Text? 

I appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: Text is for multi-line inputs, Entry is for one-line inputs. they both allow any mix of characters.

Comment: Gotcha... thank you so much Barmar! :)